# I don't understand this substring error

Tags: javascript

I noticed FireFox reports an error in my code, but can't understand what is wrong.

> [13:36:02.868] TypeError: arr[i][0].substring is not a function @ file:///home/asdf/Desktop/app/dic.js:10

Which seems to point to the ss variable line. AFAIK, I'm using it correctly (ie on the end of a string). Here the code snippet...

```
// quick array example...
var arr = [
["tammikuuta", "January"], 
["helmikuuta", "February"], 
["maaliskuuta", "March"]
]; 

function userInput(val){

var result = document.getElementById('result');
result.innerHTML = '';

if(val && val.length > 2){
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        var ss = arr[i][0].substring(0,val.length); // ss (SubString) checks the number of characters currently typed 
        if(ss.toLowerCase() !== val.toLowerCase()){ // check substring against the user input
            continue;
        }
        else { // display the output...
            var res = arr[i][1]; 
            var reg = eval('/'+val+'/i');
            var found = arr[i][0].replace(reg, '<span class="r">$&<\/span>');
            if(result.innerHTML.length > 0){
                result.innerHTML += ',<br />';
            }
            result.innerHTML += found + '<b>' + ' > ' + '</b>' + '<span class="g">' + res + '<\/span>';
        }
    }
}
else {return;}
}
```

Please advice?

**Edited: More code requested.**

Comment: did you try arr[i][0].toString().substring(0,val.length); And what does your array contain?

Comment: `arr[i][0]` simply doesn't contain a string. And if it's not a string, it won't have the method `substring`.

Comment: We can't help if you don't show us what `arr` is.

Comment: You should try `for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { console.log(typeof arr[i][0]); }` to see what type `arr[i][0]` is. Or look at how you populate that array in the first place.

Comment: This segment of your code isn't enough to be sure of what's the issue; please post more relevant code.

Comment: For the `arr` that you've shown in your edit the `arr[i][0].substring()` should work fine. (And does in isolation: http://jsfiddle.net/DMgrL/) Can you provide a demo at http://jsfiddle.net so we can see the problem happening for ourselves?

Comment: If you are interested in the full thing, here is a fiddle (with the fix): http://jsfiddle.net/aLPDg/

Comment: I removed the `.toString()` from your fiddle and it still works: http://jsfiddle.net/aLPDg/1/ - in other words, I can't reproduce your original error. (I also shrunk down that enormous yellow input and changed the fiddle's framework option on the left to "no wrap" so that your inline JS would work.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
 var ss = arr[i][0].toString()
ss = ss.substring(0,val.length);
```

Comment: I get TypeError: ss.substring is not a function

Comment: add .tostring() after array and then try

Comment: This is almost worse. Don't just blindly call `toString` on an object that you expected to be a string. This is not developing by thinking, it's guessing around and hoping it will somehow work out.

Comment: u are making it worse. have you know what that array contains?

Comment: It worked, but it's kind of weird why it didn't in the first place. It comes from var arr = [
["tammikuuta", "January"],... 
I tested typeof arr[0][0] in the console and got "string" returned. I guessed it didn't need to change , so that's why I originally left toString() off.

Comment: ok tell ingo now .. i appriciate concern of Ingo but due to some logic i asked him to add leave it. i m feeling well that i help u. and dont forget to  accept as answer :)

Comment: `[["foo","bar"]]` should be referenced as `arr[0][i]`, not `arr[i][0]`. They only coincide for `arr[0][0]`, so that was a pretty unlucky example to check the type.

Comment: Well the OP edited the question to add a sample of what `arr` actually contains: each element is an array of strings. So using `.toString()` should not be necessary to prevent the error... I would argue that (even though this answer was just accepted) `.toString()` isn't really fixing the problem, it's just covering it up.